# How can I get information from other sonarqube plugin

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I am developing a sonarqube plugin, it requires some informations like the project's location, the total line of the project, how many errors or warnings in this project, and the detail of all those errors. Those information have been collected by other plugin and what I need to do is gain those information from them, How to achieve this goal, I want the answer be specific like which document I should read or I should add what in where. please explain the answer to me as detailed as possible, I'm really a Rookie in this area.QAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [web services API](https://sonarqube.com/web_api) to access every data you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I don't konw how to use this API, is this some kind of function I can call in the code or something else? If you can show me a programming example I will be so grateful. orz